# Is AppendFormat() or AppendLine() the safer/sleeker solution?

Tags: c#, performance, append, stringbuilder, string.format

I've been creating dynamic strings to append to a StringBuilder like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string bla = "bla";
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("android:id=\"@+id/{0}\" ", bla));
```

...but then I noticed that StringBuilder has an AppendFormat() method, which obviates the "*string.Format()*". So I wondered if AppendFormat() also adds a newline, as AppendLine() does (as opposed to Append(), which doesn't).

IOW, to achieve the same effect as:

```
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("android:id=\"@+id/{0}\" ", bla));
```

...when using AppendFormat(), would I need to use two lines, like so:

```
sb.AppendFormat("android:id=\"@+id/{0}\" ", bla);
sb.AppendLine();
```

?

The answer is yes - two lines are needed, or I must revert to explicitly using string.Format() within a  call to AppendLine().

Actually, there is at least one way this can be accomplished in one line with AppendFormat(), to wit:

```
sb.AppendFormat("android:id=\"@+id/{0}\" {1}", bla, Environment.NewLine);
```

...but that is arguably no more elegant than than AppendLine(string.Format(...

So which of the following is better (more performant) or safer, or does it not matter?

```
sb.AppendFormat("android:id=\"@+id/{0}\" {1}", bla, Environment.NewLine);
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("android:id=\"@+id/{0}\" ", bla));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most readable is:

```
sb.AppendFormat("android:id=\"@+id/{0}\" ", bla)
  .AppendLine();
```

[string.Format](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#691a34e179b91fdb) uses `StringBuilder` internally, so I wouldn't go with `sb.AppendLine(string.Format())`.

Answer (score 5):

Just create your own extension method that calls both `AppendLine` and `AppendFormat`, to create the method that you want, the ability to append a line using a format string without explicitly adding the new line character:

```
public static StringBuilder AppendLineFormat(
    this StringBuilder builder,
    string formatString,
    params object[] args)
{
    return builder.AppendFormat(formatString, args)
        .AppendLine();
}
```

(Feel free to create an overload of this for each overload of `AppendFormat`, if you want to.)